# Инструменты визуализации паттерна MVC

Tags: mvc, визуализация

Есть ли программы по визуализации паттерна Model View Controller, в которых можно было бы задать имена классов, методы, связи?

Comment: Можете в [draw.io](https://draw.io) порисовать)

Comment: [Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi)

Answer (score 0):

С одной стороны, если код написан и нужно его визуализировать есть множество возможностей это сделать в разных IDE (JetBrains) и отдельных инструментах, в зависимости от языка. Если нет кода, Swagger хорошее решение, если такой уровень Вам подойдет.